# How to pass the arguments to the shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to pass the argument in the console while running a script called run.sh as follows

run.sh first count

for example:

`./run.sh first 10`

i have to pass those first and 10 to the script here

```
cat file1.txt | head -10
```

here first should refer to head and count value should be 10.
how can i do this?

Comment: Use `cat file1.txt | head $1`. `$1` refers to the first parameter, `$2`to the second, etc.

Comment: I'm curious: you list `first` as an argument, but then don't seem to use it in the script.  Did you mean to pass `file1.txt` as the argument — or to use `first` in place of `file1.txt` in the command? Also, beware of the impending [UUOC Award](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).

Answer (score 2):

### Use Positional Parameters

Bash supports [positional parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters). Parameters one through nine are stored in *$1*..*$9*, but you can have more stored in *$** or *$@*.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read x lines from some arbitrary file. 
head -n "$2" "$1"
```

Comment: If you need more than `$1` through `$9` you can use `shift`, e.g., `while $@ ; do # process options ; shift ; done`

Comment: You can also use `${10}` or so, @sigmavirus24.

Comment: True @fedorqui, I just happen to more often than not see shift used, so it seems idiomatic to me. I try to be helpful and suggest the idioms they'll see more often than not. But yes for any position > 9, `${position}` will work just fine. And if he's keeping track of it in a separate variable then `${$position}` should work.